# Why is shell pipe output truncated?

Tags: macos, bash, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code installed on macOS Catalina.  I was trying to pipe the output of `code --telemetry` to `jq` for easy reading and it failed.  This led me to discover that the pipe is truncated after 1674 lines.  What causes this?  The pipe works fine in the second example using `cat`, so I guess there is something unique about `code`.

```
$ code --telemetry | wc
    1674    3006   65536

$ code --telemetry > output.json
$ cat output.json | wc
    7530   13462  302261
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with `65536`

Answer (score 2):

It's due to **pipe** limitation.

On the Linux man page pipe(7), it says that pipe capacity is 65536 bytes (16 system pages of 4096 bytes) in others words a pipe buffer can gather 65536 characters only.

[Here is a great article to show you how to extend the pipe buffer.](https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/05/how-to-view-and-increase-default-pipe-size-buffer.html)

**EDIT :**

The issue here comes from **code** command :

A flush on **stdout** should be done before the exit, what is happening here is that **pipe** is not informed of the end of data, so **pipe** will take only the first chunk (buffer size) of 65536 bytes and then think that the stream ended and then write only the first chunk to **stdout**.

[You can report the issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/)

Comment: Then why does my second example work, piping `cat` output to `wc`?

Comment: I have edited the answer to fit with the case :)